# Creating confirmation dialog pages when Javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, django

I'm using Django and I want my users to confirm that they really want something to be deleted. I'm considering pure Django solution (no Javascript confirmations).
According to what I think,I can create a new page containing "Yes" and "No" buttons. If user presses "Yes", my site will go on and delete the object from the database.
Is it the right way to do deletion without using Javascript? How would you implement the feature if you were me?

Comment: You could check the implementation of deleting object in the Django Admin.

Comment: I guess,Django admin uses Javascript in the background to delete the object.I want no Javascript in my code though.

Comment: no it's not, just a delete view.

Comment: I disabled javascript and tried deleting the object.I was unable to delete.

Comment: I see, I mean the deletion link at the left bottom in the Change form, not the javascript deletion link in inlines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use Django's built in [`DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview), which will display a confirmation page for an HTTP `GET` request and perform deletion for an HTTP `POST` request.

The documentation gives this example:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Author
    success_url = reverse_lazy('author-list')
```

I'd recommend reading the documentation for the [`SingleObjectMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin) which explains how to customise the way the view finds the object to delete (the default is to look for an URL keyword argument called `pk`), and for the [`TemplateResponseMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin) which explains how to customise the template that is used (the default is `'myapp/author_check_delete.html'`).

This is just one of a number of [class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) that make basic operations (displaying a page for a single model instance, for a list of model instances, and handling editing, deletion etc.) very quick and easy to implement.

If you wanted to enhance this with JavaScript later you could always write some unobtrusive JS that detects links to the deletion confirmation page (by looking for a class, or a particular URL) and adds a click handler that pops up a confirmation dialog and then sends a `POST` request to the URL in the link's `href` attribute. You would also need to modify the view slightly to return a JSON object when `request.is_ajax()` is `True`, so that your JS would know if the deletion had succeeded or failed, which would probably involve overriding one of the methods inherited from the [`DeletionMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/39aa8901e11f07627958ad624146bffe0e1d05a3/django/views/generic/edit.py#L231).

Answer (score 4):

That sounds fine. What I have done a couple of times is to create a confirmation template that can be used anywhere in the application:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="confirmation-box">
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
        <div>
            <a href="{{ prev_link }}">Cancel</a>
            <form action="{{ action_link }}" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ prev_link }}" />
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

You pass to it:

- A confirmation message for the user (`message`)
- The url to the page you are in (`prev_link`)
- The url that should be called to perform the action (`action_link`)

If the user cancels the action, then she/he goes back to the original page.

If the user confirms, then the `prev_link` is passed as a hidden parameter, so the view can redirect the user to the original page after performing the action (although this is completely optional of course).

Which is pretty much what you propossed in your question.